# Stylesheet is not applied in JavaFx

Tags: java, css, javafx, stylesheet

I'm working on a JavaFX application, but I can't get the stylesheet to be applied.

My code:

```java
public class JavaFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        //set up the stage
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);

        Group root = new Group();
        root.setId("root");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(JavaFX.class.getResource("styling.css").toExternalForm());

        //Get the screensize
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double screenX = screenSize.getWidth();
        double screenY = screenSize.getHeight();

        //Text objects
        Text text = new Text();
        text.setId("text");
        text.setText("Test");
        text.setY(50);

        //Add all objects to the root group
        root.getChildren().add(text);

        //Show the stage
        primaryStage.show();

        //Calculate Positions of all objects
        text.setX((screenX /2) - text.getBoundsInParent().getWidth());
```

My Stylesheet:

```css
#text {
    -fx-font-size: 50px;
}
```

The CSS file is in the same package as the java file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of using `Toolkit`, check out [`javafx.stage.Screen`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code applies css correctly, at least I have checked with your font size and -fx-font-size: 500px; and "Text" changed as expected. Please check your styling.css file once again. (Additionally, you can always check what is compiled and look what is indeed in jar to check what is actually pulled into what you later run)

The most possible, however is that maybe you have duplicate css files with the same name, one overriding another. E.g. one in resources folder and one in the same place as your .java file

Comment: It seemed that it wasn't being compiled. Forgot to add it to build.gradle. Adding the CSS file to build.gradle fixed it, Thanks!

Comment: @TheDutchMC76 "Adding the CSS file to build.gradle fixed it"—that shouldn't be necessary. Did you have your CSS file under `src/main/resources`? By default, Gradle uses the same source directory layout as Maven. All Java source files go under `src/main/java` while all other files (i.e. resources) go under `src/main/resources`. If you want the resource to be in the same package as a class, then put them under the same relative directory (e.g. `src/main/java/com/example/JavaFX.java` and `src/main/resources/com/example/styling.css`).

Comment: @Slaw maybe also would be good to say about the fact that all resources from src/main/resources can be found on top level of the jar and later can be found by either getClass()#getResource or getClassLoader()#getResource from any object within jar no matter the package

Comment: @Slaw I didn't, did some more digging into Gradle, and indeed learned that it wasn't necessary to put it in build.gradle, I instead put it src/main/resources.